# error for too many initializes plus a function returing an array

Tags: c++

hey so I want this function to return an array with 1 row and 3 columns, don't worry about format it is needed. I'm getting too many initializes error. Also other comments would be greatly appreciated. This program is trying to find displacement between 2 particles. Here's the function implemented in my code.

```
double displacement(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2, double z1, double z2){
double ddx, ddy, ddz, ddxf, ddyf, ddzf;
double disp[1][3] = { { 0.0 }, { 0.0 }, { 0.0 } };
ddx = x1 - x2; ddy = y1 - y2; ddz = z1 - z2;
if (ddx > L / 2){
    ddxf = ddx - L;
}
else if (ddx < -L / 2){
    ddxf = ddx + L;
}
else { ddxf = ddx; }

if (ddy > L / 2){
    ddyf = ddy - L;
}
else if (ddy < -L / 2){
    ddyf = ddy + L;
}
else { ddyf = ddy; }


if (ddz > L / 2){
    ddzf = ddz - L;
}
else if (ddz < -L / 2){
    ddzf = ddz + L;
}
else { ddzf = ddz; }

return disp[1][3] = { ddxf }, { ddyf }, { ddzf } };
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. But the initializer value at the `return` seems to be missing an open-brace. If that doesn't address your question, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present a clear, answerable question.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
double disp[1][3] = { { 0.0 }, { 0.0 }, { 0.0 } };
```

to

```
double disp[1][3] = { { 0.0 , 0.0, 0.0 } };
```

The first one would be appropriate for `disp[3][1]`.

Comment: thank you I'm still new to this so I don't pick up on these things, this would also imply I should change  return disp[1][3] = {{ ddxf }, { ddyf }, { ddzf } }; to disp[1][3]={ {ddxf , ddyf , ddzf} }

Comment: @ASS466uiuc, no you can't do that since the return type of the function is `double`, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return an array from a function by value.  But, you can pass an array in by pointer and fill out the values there:

```
#include <iostream>

double *displacement(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2, double z1, double z2, double ret[3])
{
  ...

  ret[0] = ddxf;
  ret[1] = ddyf;
  ret[2] = ddzf;

  return ret;
}

int main(void)
{
  double ans[3];

  displacement(1.0, 2.0, -1.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, ans);

  std::cout << "The answer is: " << ans[0] << " " << ans[1] << " " << ans[2] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return an array from a function. Typically you could return a pointer to the first element of an array.

```
return disp[1][3] = { ddxf }, { ddyf }, { ddzf } };
```

The above does not return a pointer to the first element of disp. The following would return a pointer however:

```
return disp;
```

or

```
return &(disp[0]);
```